# Does system.speech api supports to c++ language to development?

Tags: c++, speech-recognition, sapi, system.speech.recognition, microsoft-speech-api

I'm currently doing a research on a offline desktop tool that is able to recognize to user' voice commands. For now, I look at is the possibility of using Microsoft's System.Speech API which is for desktop sapi.

In its [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361683(v=office.14).aspx), there is just some c# samples. But I need to use this api using c++ to be able implement my java application.

So my question is **Does system.speech api supports to c++ language to development ?**

Comment: System.Speech is a friendly wrapper for SAPI to provide speech support to a .NET program.  You'll have to hoof the COM interface from C++.  Sure, finding samples is going to be difficult and you'll find it rough going if you never done COM before in C++.  You are probably better off creating a [ComVisible] class library in C# and use it from Java.  You can't possibly be the first Java programmer doing this btw, a trivial google query came up with [this hit](https://github.com/chrisdevisser/Grade-12-ICS/blob/master/java_utilities/jna/Sapi.java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.  System.Speech is a managed library that runs on top of SAPI.  On the other hand, SAPI itself is a C++ library.   As Hans says, you're going to be far better off directly interacting with SAPI rather than trying to munge the .NET library into your Java app.